# t-sne scatter plot with legend

Tags: matplotlib, plot, legend, scatter

my code

X: dataset without answer

y: answer (0,1,2 or 3)

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
X_reduced = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=113.0,random_state=0).fit_transform(X)
plt.scatter(X_reduced[:, 0], X_reduced[:, 1], c=y, cmap='Greens')
plt.legend(["A","B","C","D"], loc='best')
```

then I got
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQqKA.png).

But I want "legends" with A,B,C,D corresponds to each color(light Green to dark Green)

I'd appreciate if you could answer this question.

Comment: What are the values of `y`? Are they continuous, or are there only 4 distinct values in `y`?

Comment: y=[0,1,2,3] its not continuous, but 4 distinct values. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way I have found.

Given a list of class labels, `labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']`, and an array class indices similar `y`:

```
transformed = tsne_model.fit_transform(X)

scatter = plt.scatter(transformed[:,0], transformed[:,1], c=y)
handles, _ = scatter.legend_elements(prop='colors')
plt.legend(handles, labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `y` denotes a category. then the easiest way is to loop over the different values of `y`, and plot the points with standard `plt.plot` while passing in a label:

```
# make a mapping from category to your favourite colors and labels
category_to_color = {0: 'lightgreen', 1: 'lawngreen', 2:'limegreen', 3: 'darkgreen'}
category_to_label = {0: 'A', 1:'B', 2:'C', 3:'D'}

# plot each category with a distinct label
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
for category, color in category_to_color.items():
    mask = y == category
    ax.plot(X_reduced[mask, 0], X_reduced[mask, 1], 'o', 
            color=color, label=category_to_label[category])

ax.legend(loc='best')
```